# How to show all the files that have been changed?

Tags: windows, git

I am working on a feature branch that branched off a develop branch. Now that I am ready to do a PR I just want to check which files have been changed. What git command will list all the files changed against the develop branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's diff command with the `--stat` option will show you a list of changed files without the detailed contents.

Use it like `git diff --stat origin/develop feature_branch`

If you want really basic results then you can instead use the `--name-only` option to just see the filenames and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff develop
```

Often the PR tool will show you the differences too.

For example if Microsoft's Dev Ops (previously known as VSTS) when creating a pull request you can see the changes (and commits) at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the file names, you can do

```
git diff --name-only develop
```